# issue while converting MemoryStream to Image

Tags: c#, .net

I've found some code to convert an HTML to a JPG file, however with elaborated HTML I get the invalid Base64 error, while if I pass a very basic HTML line I get a strange error "invalid parameter" while creating the image FromStream. Here is the code that I have found:

```
public static void saveURLToImage(string url, string file_name)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
    {
        string content = "";

        System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //following line will trigger "invalid Base64" error
        byte[] b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);// Convert.FromBase64String(content);
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(b);
        //following line will trigger "invalid parameter" error
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        img.Save(file_name, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        img.Dispose();
        ms.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's never going to work. You're reading HTML. You can't just pass those bytes and expect it to be a Jpeg. The reason you get errors is because it's not a Jpeg, it's HTML. You're doing the programming equivalent of renaming foo.html to foo.jpg and saying "how come it's not an image?"

Comment: can you provide a link to `some code to convert an HTML to a JPG file`?

Comment: My guess is whatever website you found that code on wasn't to convert HTML to Jpeg, but rather to download an image from a URL and to save it as a Jpeg on your pc. That's what it's doing.

Comment: In the code that you have given, can you mark the lines which are throwing the exception/error?

Comment: @displayName how do i mark lines of code?

Comment: @Plutonix this is the link: http://forums.asp.net/post/2183570.aspx

Comment: Add comment in front of the lines where you get exception so that we can know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In general...

Firstly a `Base64` string and next a `.NET Image`, **has** to meet some criteria in order to be deemed as valid.

For `Base64`:

> - The base-64 digits in ascending order from zero are the uppercase characters "A" to "Z", lowercase characters "a" to "z", numerals "0" to "9", and the symbols "+" and "/".
> - The white-space characters, and their Unicode names and hexadecimal code points, are tab (CHARACTER TABULATION, U+0009), newline (LINE FEED, U+000A), carriage return (CARRIAGE RETURN, U+000D), and blank (SPACE, U+0020).
> - An arbitrary number of white-space characters can appear in s because all white-space characters are ignored.
> - The valueless character, "=", is used for trailing padding. The end of s can consist of zero, one, or two padding characters.

For `.NET Image`, all we have from the MSDN documentation is that an `ArgumentException` is thrown in the `FromStream()` constructor if

> The stream does not have a valid image format

---

### In your case...

For the least I can say that for your first error, if your string does not fit end-to-end and if there is no padding, the code will throw.

If written properly, which I am sure the `GetBytes(string s)` is, it will perform null and length checks before attempting a conversion. *Your stream is probably not null, but the length of your stream is most likely an issue*. **There are two ways to err:**

1. **The length of s**, ignoring white-space characters, is not zero or a multiple of 4.
2. **The format of s is invalid.** s contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters.

Have you ensured that the stream you are reading has a length (excluding white spaces) equal to a multiple of four AND, if indeed the stream length is a multiple of four, then is the padding proper? The way you are reading the stream and passing it for conversion, you cannot be sure that you are providing a valid string.

Just like the string issue explained above, there is a specific way to define a valid image. I'm not informed enough to elaborate about a valid `Image`. All I know currently is that an invalid image does not parse.

Therefore, you must try to pass a valid image only. The code you have above is the code for reading a web response and not necessarily a valid image. This is why in some cases when you are able to get through the string conversion at first 'error-point', you still fail at the next one while trying to initialize an invalid image.

---

### From another perspective...

At first level, your faith, that a web response would be providing you a valid `Base64` string, is naïve. As the most basic lesson of good programming, validate  inputs from external sources.

On the next level, your faith, that the bytes created from a web response would convert into a valid image, no matter how random, is also misplaced.

---

On a side note, read through the Software Engineering gem, Steve McConnell's [Code Complete 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670).

Comment: the url that I wanted to pass is a page that I generate, so I have some sort of control over it, however cannot assure that it is multiple of 4 as there is a random component and the live data ranged from 55 to 110 characters. I guess I'll abandon the idea and find another way to protect my text data from copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

There can be several solutions to this problem. One option is to use PhantomJs to load the HTML (from an URL) and take a screenshot and save it as a jpg image. Check the [screen capture feature of PhantomJS here](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html). PhantomJs is a headless javascript library that runs on the server side. On a button click or some other event you can execute the phantomjs commends using C# at the server side.

Comment: what do you mean by headless? I cannot install or run anything as im on a shared hosting for the moment.